# Very confused $x^2$ has 1 root

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

How would you prove that $x^2$ has exactly 1 root using the rolle's theorem?

If there's f(a)>0 and f(b)=0 then f(a) does not equal f(b) does that proof that there's one root?

Answer (score 8):

Suppose there's another $a \gt 0$ without loss of generality such that $f(0) = f(a) = 0$
What does Rolle's theorem tell you?

Comment: It's a proof by contradiction - we know that 0 is a root, so suppose that there is a second root, $a$ (and there's a simple argument that lets you state that $a>0$ so you only have to do the proof on that side of 0). Then you can apply Rolle's theorem on the interval $[0, a]$.